# Refraction when angle of incidence is equal to 0 degree

Tags: refraction

Ok i know that mathematically or by snell 's law it can be proved but i want to know that what is its physical significance? I mean why it does not refract at 0 degree?

Answer (score 2):

Looked at using the [Huygens-Fresnel principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle#/media/File:Refraction_-_Huygens-Fresnel_principle.svg): each point in the wavefront will arrive on the surface at the same time. Each point is a new source emitting with the new wavelength, but as they all arrived at once, their waves are all in step so the wavefront stays the same.